# What do I do about "unresolved external symbol" errors?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

i am trying to make a list of pointers to child classes and try to find/delete objects with them with an other class

```
//class product
public:
    static vector<Product*> plist;
    static vector<Product*>::iterator tT;


//class book:public Product 
book::book(string a,double b, string c,string d,string e):Product(a,b,c),
    author(d),publisher(e)
{
    Product *k=this;
    plist.push_back(k);
}



class ProductCatalog:public Product // i really dont know how to implement this friend maybe
{
public:
    ProductCatalog();
    void findproduct(string);
    void deleteproduct();
    void addproduct();
    void listcatalog();

};

void ProductCatalog::findproduct(string temp){

    cin>>temp;
    tT=plist.begin();
    for (tT=plist.begin();tT!=plist.end();tT++){
        if((*tT)->getID()==temp)
            (*tT)->getSummery();
    }
}

void ProductCatalog::deleteproduct(){
    cout<<"enter id to delete"<<endl;
    string dd;
    cin>>dd;
    tT=plist.begin();
    for (tT=plist.begin();tT!=plist.end();tT++){
        if((*tT)->getID()==dd)
            plist.erase(tT);
    }
}
```

errors

> 1>book.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "`public: static
>   class std::vector<class Product *,class std::allocator<class Product
>   *> > Product::plist`"
>
> 1>cd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "`public: static
>   class std::vector<class Product *,class std::allocator<class Product
>   *> > Product::plist`"
>
> 1>ProductCatalog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "`public: static class std::vector<class Product *,class
>   std::allocator<class Product *> > Product::plist`"
>
> 1>ProductCatalog.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "`public: __thiscall Product::Product(void)`" (??0Product@@QAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function "`public: __thiscall
>   ProductCatalog::ProductCatalog(void)`"
>
> 1>ProductCatalog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "`public: static class std::_Vector_iterator<class
>   std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<class Product *> > >
>   Product::tT`"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574407#12574407 section "static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit"

Comment: try to use vector<shared_ptr<your_type>> also, or vector<unique_ptr<your_type>> - depending on the usage...

Comment: how am i gonna initialize vector or iterator i cant fix it